# a program to reverse each word in a string( ive read the previous solutions but im looking for one using the functions i only here

Tags: c, string, reverse, words

i've wrote this c program but im always receiving the same inputed sentence as an output without any change! i've split every word in the string and then reversed their position but it didnt work well! any solutions please!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main ()
{    
    char A[81][81];
    int t=0,j=1,k=0,l;
    puts("Input a sentence (max 80 character)");
    gets(A[0]);
    while (A[0][t]!='\0')
    {
        if(A[0][t]=='\32')
        {
            j++;
            t++;
            k=0;
        }
        A[j][k]=A[0][t];
        k++;
        t++;
    }
    for (l=j;l>0;l--)
    {
        printf("%s",A[l]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please be more explicit as to what is the inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: for example ! if i input " sami arrived to the house" the needed out " house the to arrived sami", but the output is given as the input without any reversing of the words

Comment: i divided every word in the string and placed each word in an array, i considered that the user may enter a letter instead of each word so it might take more arrays to divide those letters thanks

Comment: Someone had a question about your profile pic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283942/are-there-any-rules-and-limits-about-profile-pictures

Comment: haha its okay! wont matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void){ 
    char A[81][81] = {0};
    int t=0,j=1,k=0,l;
    puts("Input a sentence (max 80 character)");
    scanf("%80[^\n]", A[0]);//'gets' has already been abolished, it should explore a different way.
    while (A[0][t] != '\0'){
        if(A[0][t] == ' '){
            ++j;
            k=0;
            while(A[0][t] == ' ')//Skip spaces
                ++t;
        } else {
            A[j][k++] = A[0][t++];
        }
    }
    for (l=j;l>0;l--){
        printf(" %s",A[l]);
    }
    puts("");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please comment the code a bit.

Comment: Since the structure of the program are almost the same, there is a problem in the changed portion. LOL. That is rewritten as intended by the OP.

Comment: Some people seem as convinced it's incredible low ability people.